# Create a function that takes an Arraylist of any type?

Tags: java, arraylist

I had a programming assignment where i had to save separate files, one a log file and the other a dat file.  Each one took an arraylist object and saved it in the file but each arraylist was different.  I was under a time crunch so i ended up making separate functions for both but i'm wondering if there's a more modular way of doing it.  So for example:

```
 public void saveLog (ArrayList<A> objectArray, File fileName) throws IOException {
    if (!fileName.exists()) {
        logFile.createNewFile();
    }

    FileOutputStream fileoutput = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
    ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(fileoutput);
    output.writeObject(objectArray);
    output.close();
    fileoutput.close();

}
```

Is there a way to recode this so it will also take ArrayList"<"B">" ? I tried using ArrayList"<"Object">" but that threw an error. Very new to java so sorry if this seems like a simple question.

Answer (score 3):

Basically you need to accept an ArrayList which contains objects that can be serialized, this can easily be expressed with a [wildcard](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html), eg:

```
public void saveLog(ArrayList<? extends Serializable> objectArray, File fileName) {
  ..
}
```

Which means "accept an `ArrayList` of an unspecified type which implements `Serializable` interface", which is a requirement for the `ObjectOutputStream`.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the method generic on `A` (and I would prefer the `List` interface). Also, I would prefer a [`try-with-resources` Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). Like

```
public <A> void saveLog(List<A> objectArray, File fileName)
        throws IOException {
    if (!fileName.exists()) {
        logFile.createNewFile();
    }
    try (FileOutputStream fileoutput = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
            ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(fileoutput)) {
        output.writeObject(objectArray);
    }
}
```